# How to generate any color in PyX

Tags: python, colors, visualization, pyx

Many Visualisation libraries and languages provide easy ways of generating any color. for example you could simple add a style tag with a css color code to set the color of an object in html.

Is there a similiar way to set the color of a pyx drawing to any wanted color code instead of the predefined pyx color codes?

(for example something like `color.code = #1122DD` instead of `color.rgb.blue`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I found as the most convenient to have a simple RGB color:

`pyx.color.rgb(r,g,b)`

where `r, g, b` are numbers in the range `[0, 1]` and set the percentage of each base color in RGB format.

Answer (score 1):

PyX provides several color schemes for defining colors, if you want to use RGB as a hex string you can provide it as: `pyx.color.rgbfromhexstring("#1122DD")`.